# VMware Workstation cannot create ~/.vmware directory

Tags: 12.04, vmware-workstation

I just installed VMware Workstation 8.0.3 on ubuntu 12.04. Everytime it starts up it says that vmware needs `~/.vmware` to save preferences and that it is unable to create `~/.vmware`.

But `~/.vmware` is already a directory. How do I get this resolved?

Comment: This might be a permissions problem, *caused* by having run VMware as `root` (but there are other possible causes too). Please edit your question to add the output of these three commands (run them in the Terminal, which you can open by pressing `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T`): [1] `ls -ldh ~/.vmware` [2] `ls -lRh ~/.vmware` [3] `df -h` Please also add the complete and exact text of the error messages, as well as the the text you get in the Terminal when you try to start `vmware` there (when it's not already running).

Comment: This helped on **Ubuntu 14.04 64bit** and **Workstation 10.02**: sudo chown -R username:username ~/.vmware Thanks for helping this out **ldgriffin** and **daviderault** Regards

Answer (score 12):

You should never run as root unless you are explicitly trying to modify your system.  VMWare Workstation does not need root access to simply run a guest machine.  Likely your permission were changed to root owning your `~/.vmware` folder during install.  You just need to change the ownership back to your user.

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.vmware
```

This will set the owner back to you and your group.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with VMWare Player 6.0 in Ubuntu 13.10

I solved it by using:

```
chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.vmware
```

Answer (score -1):

Try running as `root`, it always helps get things done.

Comment: Running as root will *not* help an issue of writing to one's home folder. Read the error carefully, please.

Comment: It might, since the problem is that part of the user's home folder has come to be owned by `root`. It's still a bad idea though--instead, [ownership should be retaken on the affected files](http://askubuntu.com/a/154728/22949).